# Django - redirect from one app to another app's page Django

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications, django-views

I have two apps called **shop** and **subapp_gallery** . Basically, subapp_gallery contains photo albums.. In my shop app I have my homepage for the website. so how can I redirect from link in a homepage[links to each albums] to subapp_gallery's albums path.both apps are working without errors. Thanks in advance.

**--image attached down--**

```
>shop_project
>>settings.py
>>urls.py

>shop
>>apps.py
>>models.py
>>urls.py
>>views.py

>subapp_gallery
>>apps.py
>>models.py
>>urls.py
>>views.py
```

This is urls.py file in shop app >>

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.shop, name='shop-home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='shop-about'),
    path('pricing', views.pricing, name='shop-pricing'),    
]
```

This is urls.py file in subapp_gallery app >>

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<topic_name>\w+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
    url(r'^(?P<topic_name>\w+)/(?P<photo_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')
]
```

[shop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOk2l.png)

[subapp_gallery app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dHu7.png)

Comment: You should post code and images in StackOverflow instead of providing links.

Comment: And you need to further explain what the problem is. Apps are just logical groupings, Django doesn't care what's in which app from the point of view of redirecting.

Comment: @saurav it's a StackOverflow image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's silly question. just used "{%  url 'topic' %}"and It worked. django is smart enough to know which name from which application.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who will need this.If you have two apps ,shop and sub_gallery, and you need a view in shop.views.py to redirect  to a view of the other app, here's what you can do:


*Assuming:
1.The the view for redirecting is called redirect_view
2.This view takes one arg(int)
3.Name of the url in sub_gallery.url.py is redirect_view:*

```
 #In shop.views.py:
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
....
#the view that redirects to sub_gallery app
def redirect_view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sub_gallery:redirect_view',args=(1',))



#In shop.urls.py:
...
from sub_gallery.views import receiving_view
app_name='shop'

urlpatterns=[
...
path('redirect_view/<int:number>/',receiving_view,name='receiving_view'),



#In sub_gallery.urls.py:
app_name='sub_gallery'
...
urlpatterns=[
...
path('receiving_view/<int:number>/',views.receiving_view,name='receiving_view')
]



#In sub_gallery.views.py

....
from django.shortcuts import render
def receiving_view(request,number):
    context={'dummy':number}
    return render(request,'somefile.html',context)
```

Note that my directory structure is: 
**->shop
->sub_gallery**
not
**->shop/sub_gallery**.
Just do some modifications and it'll work.
With *DEBUG=False*, you'll see the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [naming url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

You can use `reverse('<namespace>:<urlname>')` to get the url you want to redirect to.

Comment: tried it,didn't work for me and didn't get it 100% how to use this in a correct way